# MVP Generics Issue (Java)

Tags: java, generics, mvp

I am trying to write a interfaces and default implementations of the MVP pattern. However, I am receiving an error message on something that I think should be possible. The error message that I receive is:

```
required: CAP#1
  found: MVPPresenter<M,V>
  reason: actual argument MVPPresenter<M,V> cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion
  where V,M,P are type-variables:
    V extends IMVPView< ? extends IMVPPresenter< ?,V>> declared in class MVPPresenter
    M extends Object declared in class MVPPresenter
    P extends IMVPPresenter< ?,? extends IMVPView< P>> declared in interface IMVPView
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends IMVPPresenter< ?,V> from capture of ? extends IMVPPresenter< ?,V>
```

This does not make sense to me because MVPPresenter should be a CAP#1. Can someone please explain why I can't do this or provide a way to fix the problem?

```
/**
 * Interface for the presenter in MVP
 *
 * @param <M> Model type
 * @param <V> View type
 */
public interface IMVPPresenter<M, V extends IMVPView<? extends IMVPPresenter<?, V>>> {
    ...
}

/**
 * Interface for the view in MVP
 *
 * @param <P> Presenter type
 */
public interface IMVPView<P extends IMVPPresenter<?, ? extends IMVPView<P>>> {
    ...
    public void setPresenter(P presenter);
}

/**
 * Default implementation of the presenter interface
 *
 * @param <M> Model Type
 * @param <V> View Type
 */
public class MVPPresenter<M, V extends IMVPView<? extends IMVPPresenter<?, V>>>
    implements IMVPPresenter<M, V> {
    ...
    protected void setView(V view) {
        ...
        view.setPresenter(this); // Error on this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concrete classes must be … well a bit more concrete.

```
public class MVPPresenter<M, V extends IMVPView<MVPPresenter<M,V>>>
  implements IMVPPresenter<M, V> {

  protected void setView(V view) {
    view.setPresenter(this); // No more error on this line
  }
}
```

Comment: For all intensive purposes this works for me. The only thing that bothers me is that now the view says that it only works with the default implementation of the presenter interface. However, the view should only have to say that it works with all presenters which can handle this view regardless of whether the default implementation of the presenter was used or not.

Comment: You can widen the signature to `public class MVPPresenter<M, V extends IMVPView<IMVPPresenter<M, V>>> implements IMVPPresenter<M, V>`. Then the view can work with more types of presenters.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally understand why my original idea did not work. However, my original code is what I need, so I decided to push the setPresenter method to the child class and everything finally works.